# Alter table with enum column gives mysql error in php script

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to run following script from codeigniter model

```
   public function query_te($query){       
    $this->log_d->query($query);
    $data = array();
    if($this->log_d->_error_number()){
        $msg = "MySQL error ".$this->log_d->_error_number().": ".$this->log_d->_error_message()."\nWhen executing <br>\n$query\n<br>";
        $data['error'] = 1;
        $data['msg']=$msg;
    }else{
        $msg = "Success";
        $data['error'] = 0;
        $data['msg']=$msg;  
    }
    return $data;
  }
```

I am calling following section from controller

```
   $qry="ALTER TABLE page_ids CHANGE connected_user connected_user ENUM( 'CO', 'CON_s', 'CON', 'F', 'S' ) NOT NULL;";
   $return_dat= $this->sql_mig->query_te($qry);
```

Even script executed fine and change column structure in db but it still gives error as following:

```
    MySQL error 1065: Query was empty When executing
```

Comment: What is `$this->log_d`?  In particular, how is its `_error_number()` function defined?

Comment: $this->log_d is database object from codeigniter. _error_number() is function from codeigniter which gives mysql_errno.

Comment: I can find neither `log_d` nor `_error_number()` in CodeIgniter documentation and source.  Also, Google searches for either of those terms together with "codeigniter" only bring up this question.  I don't use CodeIgniter myself, so I could well be wrong, but somehow I suspect that isn't entirely correct.